# Select MALFORMED_QUERY

Tags: soql, query

I am trying to make this select:

```
select COD_CID__c, COD_CID__r.Name, CreatedDate from Hipoteses_Diagnosticos__c where CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS: 365 GROUP BY COD_CID__c, COD_CID__r.Name ORDER BY COUNT(COD_CID__c) DESC, CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 10
```

But the following error is returned:

```
MALFORMED_QUERY: Ordered field must be grouped or aggregated: CreatedDate
```

And if I try to put 'CreatedDate' in my 'GroupBy', the error below is returned:

```
field 'CreatedDate' can not be grouped in a query call
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: You haven't explained what you're attempting to do, so an answers we give you are going to be only educated guesses. Please [edit] your question to include a description of what your goals are, so that we may better help you. Please read about [ask] for more information on what expect from a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actual problem of your query is that you added `count(COD_CID__c)` in order by clause. i would recommend go through  [SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_sosl_intro.htm) as per doc.

> Note the following when using COUNT():

COUNT() must be the only element in the SELECT list.

You can use COUNT() with a LIMIT clause.

You can't use COUNT() with an ORDER BY clause. Use COUNT(fieldName) instead.

You can't use COUNT() with a GROUP BY clause for API version 19.0 and later. Use COUNT(fieldName) instead.